# Split a string message into 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, string

I have a message coming containing 48 different values seperated as:

`String values = "4774,55567,44477|14555,4447,5687|416644,4447,5623|...";`

I need to convert it into 16 by 3 array as:

`String[,] vals = {{"4774,55567,44477"},{14555,4447,5687},{416644,4447,5623}...}`

I tried using the `split()` function but cannot figure how to feed it into the matrix

Comment: You are asking to get a multidimensional array here (_[,]_) but for all practically purposes you can just use a jagged array (_[],[])_ With the limited info provided by your question I could suggest to use a jagged array because you get the advantage to convert your string to a jagged array with just one line of code

Comment: Try : String[][] vals = values.Split(new char[] { '|' })
                .Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToArray()).ToArray();

Answer (score 1):

You can split it two times:

```
var values = "4774,55567,44477|14555,4447,5687|416644,4447,5623";
var rows = values.Split('|');
var matrix = new string[rows.Length][];
for (var i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = rows[i].Split(',');
}
```

and a more elegant solution using LINQ:

```
var values = "4774,55567,44477|14555,4447,5687|416644,4447,5623";
var data = values
    .Split('|')
    .Select(r => r.Split(','))
    .ToArray();
```

EDIT: as @RandRandom pointed out, the solution above creates a jagged array. The difference is explained here: [link](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/multidimensional-arrays-csharp). If the jagged array is not an option for you, to create a 2d array you need to create a `matrix`, specifying the dimensions `[rows.Length, rows[0].Split(',').Length]` and with the help of 2 for-loops assign the values:

```
string values = "4774,55567,44477|14555,4447,5687|416644,4447,5623";
string[] rows = values.Split('|');
string[,] matrix = new string[rows.Length, rows[0].Split(',').Length];
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
{
    string[] rowColumns = rows[i].Split(',');
    for (int j = 0; j < rowColumns.Length; j++)
    {
        matrix[i, j] = rowColumns[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Though it is a jagged array and not a multidimensional array (2d)

Answer (score 0):

You can `split the string based on the | character`. Then, using `linq.Select()`, split each line based on `,` and create a two-dimensional array

```
string[] temp = values.Split('|');
var res=temp.Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq if you can consider the jagged array instead of 2D array:

```
var values = "4774,55567,44477|14555,4447,5687|416644,4447,5623";
var result = values
   .Split('|')
   .Select(x => x.Split(','))
   .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String.Split() method to split the string into an array of substrings, and then use a nested loop to iterate through the array and add the values to the 2D array.

Here is an example :

```
string values = "4774,55567,44477|14555,4447,5687|416644,4447,5623|...";
string[] substrings = values.Split('|');
string[,] vals = new string[substrings.Length,3];
for (int i = 0; i < substrings.Length; i++)
{
    string[] subvalues = substrings[i].Split(',');
    for (int j = 0; j < subvalues.Length; j++)
    {
        vals[i, j] = subvalues[j];
    }
}
```

This will split the string values by the separator '|' and create an array of substrings. Then, it will iterate through each substring and split it again by ',' and store the result in a 2D array vals with 16 rows and 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            string values = "4774,55567,44477|14555,4447,5687|416644,4447,5623";
            String[][] vals = values.Split(new char[] { '|' }).Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToArray()).ToArray();

            string[,] vals2 = new string[vals.GetLength(0), vals[0].Length];
            for(int i = 0; i < vals.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < vals.Length; j++)
                {
                    vals2[i, j] = vals[i][j];
                }
            }
```